# C++ Move assignment operator

Tags: c++11

I am attempting to use operator overloading of the '&' and '|' and '|=' operators of C++ inorder to create a BNF (Backus Naur Form) embedded in C++. 
The two significant classes in this embedded BNF are class Terminal and class NonTerminal.

As example Snippet, consider the BNF description of a list of the characters 'a' or 'b':

```
Terminal _a('a'), _b('b');
NonTerminal list, token;

token |= _a | _b;

list |= token | token & list;   

// Parse a string of 'a's and 'b's
if(list.match("baabaabaa"))
  cout << "matched!!!";
else
  cout << "failed!!!";

// Test the token nonterminal
token.match("a");
```

The class definitions are as follows: They don't do anything at the moment but serve as a test of the logic.

```
using namespace std;

class Sequence;
class Production;

class Base {
  Base() {}
  virtual ~Base() {}

  friend Sequence operator & (const Base& lhs, const Base& rhs);
  friend Production operator | (const Base& lhs, const Base& rhs);

  virtual bool match(string) const { return false; }
};

class Terminal : public Base {
  char token;
public:
  Terminal(char c) : token(c) {}
  virtual ~Terminal() {}

  virtual bool match(string s) const { return true; }  
};

class Sequence : public Base {
  const Base& lhs;
  const Base& rhs;
public:
  Sequence(const Base& lhs, const Base& rhs) : lhs(lhs), rhs(rhs) {}
  virtual ~Sequence() {} 
  virtual bool match(string s) const { return lhs.match(s) && rhs.match(s); }
};

class Production: public Base {
  const Base& lhs;
  const Base& rhs;
public:
  Production(const Base& lhs, const Base& rhs) : lhs(lhs), rhs(rhs) {}
  virtual ~Production() {} 
  virtual bool match(std::string s) const { return lhs.match(s) || rhs.match(s); }
};
```

The last class definition, NonTerminal, is where I am having trouble. And the trouble involves C+11 move semantics.

```
class NonTerminal : Base {
  Base dummy; // Needed to make initialization work.
  Base& ref; // Or maybe Base&& ref or possibly Base ref or could it be Base* ref?

  NonTerminal() : ref(dummy) {}
  virtual ~NonTerminal() {}

  // Used when rhs is of type Sequence or Production
  void operator |= (Base&& rhs) {
    // The desired action is to capture rhs and keep it in memory.
    ref = move(rhs); 
  }

  // Used when rhs is of type Terminal
  void operator |= (const Base& rhs) {
    // The desired action is to reference rhs. 
    ref = rhs;
  }

  virtual bool match(string s) { return ref.match(s); } 
};
```

The code that the above example is based on compiles but when 'list.match()' is called, it calls the method Base::match() and not Production::match() which is the expected behaviour.  In the same manner, calling token.match() also calls the method Base::match() and not Terminal::match(). So how do I get the correct overwritten match methods called and do it correctly for the rvalue received in the first operator |= method?

Thanks

Comment: You seem to believe that `ref = move(rhs);` makes `ref` refer to `rhs`. Instead, it moves `rhs` into `dummy`, [slicing it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) in the process. That's how you lose all polymorphic behavior.

Comment: @HammerJ: Use pointer instead of reference to prevent object slicing. Then you will get polymorphic behavior.